# Please explain the refresh process that yodlee employs..

Tags: yodlee

Please explain the refresh process that is employed when refreshing transaction data, answering the following questions:

1) How often does this refresh happen?
2) What time does it happen?
3) Does it happen at different times for different institutions?
4) IF a refresh fails for a particular account for one user, how is that handled?
5) What happens if all txs from one bank for all users fails?

Answer (score 0):

1) How often does this refresh happen?

Yodlee does a refresh on a daily basis during a 19 hour window. This also depends upon the type of account and also the error state of that account.

Example - Bank / Credit card accounts are refreshed on a daily basis but loan and mortgage are refreshed on a weekly basis.
Also account in a 402(invalid credential) error is not refreshed at all.

2) What time does it happen?

Between 10 am to 5 am PST.

3) Does it happen at different times for different institutions?

No, it's dependent on the automatic refresh logic of Yodlee. It doesn't vary based on institutions.

4) IF a refresh fails for a particular account for one user, how is that handled?

Depending on the error code the next refresh is scheduled. If the refresh failed with UAR then account is never refreshed by Yodlee. If refresh failed by agent or site error , then the refresh is again scheduled for a later time.

For error codes please refer [error_code document](http://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes)

5) What happens if all txs from one bank for all users fails?

If the refresh fails then no new transaction is scraped and old transactions will still be with Yodlee.