# Is there anyway to stop a daily automatic Yodlee refresh

Tags: yodlee

I have read this article

[Please explain the refresh process that yodlee employs..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628533/please-explain-the-refresh-process-that-yodlee-employs)

We understand this happens within a 19 hour window, is there anyway to stop the automatic refresh (the initial refresh on a Site based AddAccount1 is fine) - so that the subsequent refreshes can be manually controlled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic refresh can be turned off for any client by Yodlee. You can contact the customer care team by logging a service request through YCC(Yodlee customer care ) tool and they will help you with that.